# AngularJS two-way binding not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I can't seem to find an answer here. So I'm asking what I'm doing wrong. I have a method that measures the height of the screen and divides by the height of a div in order to decide how many to display at a time and page the remaining divs in the list. Problem is, I can't do the measuring when the directive is loaded because the div list hasn't been loaded so it needs to be measured when the container div comes into view. This means that I need to update a controller scope variable and have it reflected in the directive scope. Enter two way binding! It's not working though so... your help would be appreciated. Code below...

```
var app = angular.module('main');

app.directive('itemList', function(ItemListService){
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attributes){
        //this function just initializes the values to be updated
        scope.pagedItems = ItemListService.adaptItemstoFitPage(scope.items);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/item-list.html',
        link: linkFunction,
        scope: {
             items: "=",
             pagedItems: "="
        }
});
```

HTML

```
<item-list paged-items="pagedItems" items="items"></item-list>
```

In the controller there is a method that runs when the button to display this list of divs is clicked and they are loaded into the DOM

```
$scope.pagedItems = ItemListService.adaptItemsToFitPage($scope.items);
```

It runs the above method which updates $scope.pagedItems, yet that isn't reflected in the directive. What have I done wrong? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if `replace: true` is messing with the two way binding? Since it replaces your <item-list /> with the template html that doesn't have the original binding setup? Just a hunch since this looks right everywhere else.

Comment: I think the fact that you reassign the `pagedItems` property of your scope in the `link` function beraks the binding. The `pagedItems` property then refers to an in-memory collection, and not to the observed bound variable.

Comment: Hugues, I just did a test based on what you said and you're right, it broke the binding... But I thought it was supposed to be two way? If i change it there, it should update the parent scope too shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, the thing is, when you change it in the link, the directive forgets it is a bound property completely, and considers the new array as the value. angular stops watching it and syncing the outside and inside scopes. I would suggest to use a controller in conjunction with your directive to initialize your property, instead of the link function.